# Script stopping when storing a session var in a javascript var

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting ~ 2k cities name from my Database that I am storing in a session variable, then I am trying to convert my session variable into a javascript variable but my code seem to crash

Code for session variable

```
    $sql = "SELECT nom FROM Villes ORDER BY nbSearch";
    try
    { $resultat = $bd->Select($sql); }
    catch(Exception $e)
    { echo $e->getMessage(); }

    if(count($resultat) != 0)
        $_SESSION['villeDB'] = $resultat;

    echo count($resultat)."<br/>";
```

php to javascript

```
var availableTags = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['villeDB']) ?>';
```

I need to store each city name into that kind of JavaScript var

```
var availableTags = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting quotes:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['villeDB']) ?>;
```

---

If you want to convert `[["Acme, AB"],["Airdrie, AB"],...]` to `["Acme, AB","Airdrie, AB",...]`, you can use something like

```
var temp = [];
for (var i=0; i<availableTags.length; ++i) {
    for (var j=0; j<availableTags[i].length; ++j) {
        temp.push( availableTags[i][j] );
    }
}
availableTags = temp;
```

but if you ask it in another question maybe someone will answer a better option.

Comment: Yes it was that, Thanks. At the moment, my var availableTags contains element like this : var availableTags = [["Acme, AB"],["Airdrie, AB"],.. how can i remove the second square bracket to get something like this : var availableTags = ["Acme, AB","Airdrie, AB" ... ?

Comment: Can only accept the answer in 3 minutes, do i need to open a new "ticket" about my square bracket problem ?